# Reverse dots and boxes

Tags: strategy, game, game-theory, pencil-and-paper-games, dots-and-boxes

> Alice and Bob are playing a game of reverse [dots and boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes). The rules are simple:
>
> - The players take turns adding one horizontal or vertical line in one free spot on the grid (marked with light gray lines in the below image). Alice goes first.
> - If a move completes a $1\times1$ box, the player gets one point and has to make another move. The player keeps making moves until they make a move which does not complete a $1\times1$ box.
> - The game ends when all possible lines have been drawn.
> - Since this is a *reverse* game, the player with the most points **loses**.
>
> [image]

Which of the players can win the game played in the above grid? What strategy should they use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest an alternate (simpler) strategy:

> By sacrificing five squares immediately, Alice can be assured of victory
>  
>  [image: Assured Victory]
>  
>  Then by splitting the remaining 6 into 2x3 chunks, Bob has no option but to fill in the remaining 6.
>  
>  Using this strategy ***Alice always wins.***
>  
>  As pointed out by LeppyR64 - if Alice does not take boxes from the outset, and only creates a 2 or 3 block section, Bob can always win by taking 3 boxes, and leave her with 3+2+3 or 2+3+3

Comment: This solution also invalidates the other two answers.  If the other two solutions are attempted then Bob wins.

Comment: This is the intended answer. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

**My solution...**

> The grid contains $11$ boxes. You can split them up into $2+2+2+2+3$ or $2+3+3+3$. So the first sum is $4$ moves and the second sum is $3$ possible moves.
>
>   The last player who can set a line without enclosing one box wins, because his opponent will enclose one box after the next. Enclosing means, that you can't set a line in this area without making a $1×1$ box.
>
>   The player who starts wants to make the second sum, because it is $3$ moves (first player, second player, first player, now the second  player will enclose all boxes). The second player wants to make the first sum, because it is $4$ moves. So if the first player plays good he will win because he encloses $3$ boxes, then the second player will enclose $2$ boxes, because $3$ would mean the second sum. Then the first player will enclose $3$ boxes for the second sum.

**Images:**
Enclose **3** boxes:

> [image]

Enclose **2** boxes:

> [image]